# Get data from database when u onlw know the row number and column name

Tags: view

how to get data from ms access database when u only know the column name and row number ?

example

```
select empID 
from table 
where row no is x
```

Comment: Do you know the table name?  Also, what version of MS Access?

Comment: visCard and ms access 2013

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the 15th records is to use the TOP command twice.  First, get the 15 records order by id asc.  Then take the top 1 record order by id.  That assumes you know a field in the record (table) that you can order by.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
    SELECT top 15 *
    FROM [Order Details] d
    ORDER BY d.[Order Id] asc
) q
ORDER BY d.[Order Id] desc
```

The above query works fine in MS Access 2007.

[image]

I will see if there is some indicator in the MS Access system tables that are not well documented.

While there is a MSysObjects hidden table and LvProp (L-Value Property), it is a long binary data type.

It looks to me that MS Access is storing the data in a binary format.  However, there is no DBCC PAGE to view the internal record structure.

In short, I think the solution above using TOP and/or COUNT is the only way to go.